# Angular 6 how to pass the configuration to the external library in app.module.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I want to pass some basic configuration to the external / third party module. This basic configuration is in JSON file so that it can be easily modify for different environment without rebuilding the code.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyTestModule } from '@my-test-module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// I want to eliminate this require statement 
const myConstant = require('./someConfigs.json');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyTestModule.forRoot(myConstant.appCode)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here i want to pass the `appcode` to the `@my-test-module`. But the only way which i found is using `require` statement which is not good in case of tree shaking. Do anyone knows better solution for this?

Comment: why dont you create an angular service to return this json file and then import this service into your code wherever necessary

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST/DIRTY SOLUTION**

You can basically use `declare var myConstant`.

It tells your compiler that the variable exists somewhere so it doesn't thrown any error while compiling.

You then load a js file initializing `myConstant` in your index.html `<head>` (it has to be loaded BEFORE all your app js) tag from whatever source is convenient for you *i.e a remote server* via a `<script>` tag.

Example :

`config.js` hosted on your server :

```
var myConstant = {appCode : whateverYouWant }
```

Loaded on your app in the head tag :

```
<script src="//yourserver.com/config.js"></script>
```

Used in your component like this :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyTestModule } from '@my-test-module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

declare var myConstant;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyTestModule.forRoot(myConstant.appCode)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**SECOND/CLEANER SOLUTION**

Use `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` files into a `"/src/environment"` folder that contains variables for each environments.

An example :

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  appCode: WHATEVERYOUWANT
};
```

Loaded into your component like this :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyTestModule } from '@my-test-module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {environment} from "./environments/environment"

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyTestModule.forRoot(environment.appCode)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: The solution that you have provided works if the configuration is in typescript file (.ts) and not in json file. I want to read the configuration from json file only.

Comment: @nikhil So I can recommend you to use the first solution I gave you, the javascript file you load just read the json file and store it into a variable

Comment: @nikhil Your index.html load the .js file that itselft initialize its variables from reading the .json file into your server

Comment: hi, can i change the `<script src="//yourserver.com/config.js"></script>` to something local like `<script src="./config/config.js"></script>` ?